# How to manage payload during interaction with multiple endpoints in a SI flow

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to understand the options available for handling payload within a SI flow that communicates with multiple endpoints.

I have a web service entry point defined using **int-ws:inbound-gateway**. It receives a SOAP message with the below payload:

**SOAP Request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <emp:Employee>
     <emp:EmpId>sf</emp:EmpId>
     <emp:EmpName></emp:EmpName>
    </emp:Employee>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The SI flow then extracts EmpId and passes it as a **string** payload to a JMS queue.  The JMS endpoint replies with Employee Name as a **string** type. SI flow then maps Employee Name to element **EmpName** in the response message.

**SOAP response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <emp:Employee>
     <emp:EmpId>sf</emp:EmpId>
     <emp:EmpName>Spring Framework</emp:EmpName>
    </emp:Employee>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To implement this use case I have used **Claim Check** pattern. Also used **header** to store the reply from the JMS endpoint.

It will be great help if you could suggest any other approach considering the fact that the SI flow could communicate with other endpoints (each having their own data exchange format) in addition to the JMS endpoint.  Also I would want to  avoid using header to store the JMS reply payload.

## Config file

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="ws-inbound-emp-gateway" request-channel="ws-requests"  
                        marshaller="jaxbMarshaller"  unmarshaller="jaxbMarshaller"
                        header-mapper="customMapper"  />

<int:chain input-channel="ws-requests" output-channel="responsePipe">
    <int:claim-check-in message-store="simpleMessageStore"/>
    <int:header-enricher>
      <int:header  name="msgId" expression="payload"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:transformer   expression="headers['msgId']"/>
    <int:claim-check-out message-store="simpleMessageStore" remove-message="false"/>

    <int:transformer expression="payload.getEmpId()"/>

    <int-jms:outbound-gateway   request-destination="requestQueue" reply-destination="responseQueue" 
                                requires-reply="true"/>     
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="responsePipe"  >
    <int:header-enricher>
      <int:header name="empNameResponse" expression="payload"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

   <int:transformer   expression="headers['msgId']"/>
   <int:claim-check-out message-store="simpleMessageStore" remove-message="true"/>

    <int:enricher>
      <int:property name="empName"  expression="headers['empNameResponse']"/>
    </int:enricher>
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case I only see [Content Enricher](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html) pattern, which is implement as
[`<enricher>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher) in Spring Integration.

So, what you need to unmarshal your XML request to the POJO, e.g. using JAXB. Configure several `<enricher>` and map downstream replies to an appropriate property of your POJO.

In the end, after all phases, you should just marshal the final POJO to the XML back and send as a response via SOAP.

The sample is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/enricher).

Comment: Thanks @Artem. Your solution perfectly suits my use case.